# columns order preference left join in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, left-join

```
$select->from(array('b1'=>'books_master'), 'b1.book_id');

$select->joinLeft(array('b2'=>'books_details'), 'b1.book_id = b2.book_id', 'b2.book_id');
```

This is returning `null`, i.e. the value of `b2.book_id` if not found in matching row in right table.

Record is there in `books_master` but not in `books_details`.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of the `joinleft` method must be an **array** of the the columns you want to get.

Please see the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join)

> **LEFT JOIN** with the `joinLeft(table, condition, [columns])` method.
>
> All rows from the left operand table are included, matching rows from the right operand table included, and the columns from the right operand table are filled with `NULL` if no row exists matching the left table.

You code should be :

```
$select->from(array('b1'=>'books_master'), 'b1.book_id');
$select->joinLeft(array('b2'=>'books_details'), 'b1.book_id = b2.book_id', 
                  array('b2.book_id'));
```

Comment: thats ok @blackbishop. I think you dint get my problem, the above code is returning "null", the value of "b2.book_id" which is specified in "joinLeft" function, instead of returning the non-null value of "b1.book_id", which is specified in "from()" clause. Which ideally it should return as it is the left operand table column.